# import { styled } from '@mui/material/styles'; displayName not showing

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

Using Mui styled function to style both jsx elements and MUI components. The displayName is not showing when I debug the element in Chrome or any browser for that matter.
Anyone know how to fix this.
I'm using Vite for my setup.

```
const MyComponent = styled('div')`
  display: flex;
`;
```

As you can see from the below screenshot its not showing MyComponent display name instead its showing css-1vht943

[image]

Comment: You are not supposed to see the 'displayName' in the Elements panel of the DevTools.

Comment: @KostasMinaidis where is the docs does it say you are not supposed to see the displayName ?

Comment: Basically, it's from my own experience but you can get some hints from these 2 pages from the official docs mentioning that you can see the displayName in the React Developers Tools: 

https://reactjs.org/docs/higher-order-components.html#convention-wrap-the-display-name-for-easy-debugging

https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#displayname

Comment: Remember that JSX is transpiled to JS and HTML, so you end up seeing only HTML elements in the Inspector. It's through the React DevTools that you can actually inspect the React structure and the Components themselves.

Comment: Right its dev tools that i'm using Chrome dev tools.

Answer (score 0):

You can see `class` only inside the Element tab. When you click on one of the lines which contains the `class` name.

You can find all the `CSS` related to that class under the `styles` tab including `display` name for your case. Please check the image below

[image]

Comment: I updated my image to show I don't see displayName in the Elements or styles column. See new image in my post. Are you using import { styled } from '@mui/material/styles';

Comment: Yes, I'm using the same import as you. In your image, You are selecting wrong div. That is not your styled component. If you select div inside the currently selected div, you will find the display property inside it.

Comment: If you look closely, The div with class css-dsmo6d showing "flex" in front of it. It means that div contains flex property and that is your actual styled component.

Comment: Right but yours cleary shows the DisplayName at the stat of the class name in elements. Mine does not.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to have a name I think you can use `styled('div', { name: 'MyTheme'})`, then you will see something like `<div class="css-t7mscw-MyTheme-root"></div>`. Don't know if this is what you want, but [here](https://mui.com/system/styled/#custom-components) it is vaguely mentioned in the doc.

Comment: Thanks for this. Yes I know about this way of getting ti to show but I want it to be automated like style-components and @motions does it automatically for you. No need to pass a name property to each component.